# Dealing with an empty Session in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, session, exception

I have a question about empty session and "try-catch" handling.

I have few forms that use a session to pass data one to each other and sometime when the user is stay for a long time on specific page he cannot continue to the next page because the session is empty.

I want to handle it somehow but i have no idea.

Answer (score 2):

On page load of the next page, check if the user has valid session, if not then redirect to the login page.
Suppose you store user's login id in `LoginID` field of the session, then you can check as following

```
if(Session["LoginID"]==null || Convert.ToString(Session["LoginID"])==string.Empty)
{
//Redirect to login page
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Session` is a collection.

You can use its `Count` property.

```
if(Session.Count == 0)
{
   // session is empty
}
```

Comment: ok but what should i do if the session is empty? because the user cant go to the next page if the session is empty

Comment: If session is empty, my above if condition will execute